# Cant figure out why I am getting an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0, run time error

Tags: java, arrays

I can't figure out why I am getting this runtime error. Java is telling me that line 17 is the issue.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class whatIsWrong {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = 0;
        String[] names;
        names = new String[size];
        System.out.printf("%nEnter number of names desired names:  ");
        size = input.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           System.out.printf("%nName #%d:  ", i +1);
           names[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move `names = new String[size];` after the line `size = input.nextInt();`

Comment: Voting to close as *"This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers."*

Comment: `names = new String[size]; ` you declared `size = 0;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy the problem currently is that you initialize an array with the size `0`. In the for loop you get the new size so the array length isn't equal to the size.

You need to initialize the array after the `size = input.nextInt()` line.

So it should look like that:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class whatIsWrong {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = 0;

        System.out.printf("%nEnter number of names desired names:  ");
        size = input.nextInt();

        String[] names = new String[size];

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%nName #%d:  ", i +1);
            names[i] = input.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

**For short:**

Changing the value of `size` will not affect the size of the array `names`, which is `0`.

**Detailed explanation:**

When `names = new String[size];` is executed, the value of size is `0`, so the sieze of the String array `names` is `0`, eventhough `size` is changed afterwards, that will not change the size of `names`. So it is an **empty** array. By visiting `names[0]` in the first round of the `for` loop, you are assuming that it has at lest one element.